Don't trigger build run when the changes occur in specific folder
I am trying to skip build pipeline run whenever there is any file changes inside the folder named 'Documentation'. We have different repositories where developers add documentation inside 'Documentation' folder. This folder could be anywhere within the repository. Some team adds in root level, some inside main folder etc.
How can i setup exclude rule in my yaml file so that it doesn't trigger build run whenever there is file changes inside the Documentation folder.
Scenario 1: when the Documentation folder is in root.

My yaml looks like this:
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
   - main
   - releases/*
 paths:
   include:
   - *
   exclude:
   - Documentation/*

Scenario 2: when the Documentation folder is one folder inside:

My yaml looks like this:
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
   - main
   - releases/*
 paths:
   include:
   - *
   exclude:
   - **/Documentation/**

As you can see i have to keep updating exclude script depending upon where the Documentation folder is. Is there an option within yaml file to exclude changes inside Documentation folder no matter where it exists in repo, so that i don't have to keep updating exlude part per different repo?

What happens if you include both **/Documentation/* and Documentation/*?

that will work on above scenario but it won't if let's say documentation folder was Folder1/Folder1/Documentation level

I tested the following yaml with 'Documentation/*' and '**/Documentation/*' in the exclude part and it works. This configuration will exclude any changes in the ‘Documentation’ folder at any level in the directory structure, including the root and the path such as Folder1/Folder1/Documentation.
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
   - main
   - releases/*
 paths:
   include:
   - '*'
   exclude:
   - 'Documentation/*'
   - '**/Documentation/*'

I changed the files under any of the Documentation folders and it will not trigger the pipeline.
Example files:


That worked. compared with mine and i had '/Documentation/', changing to similar to yours i.e. '**/Documentation/*' did the trick. Thank you

Does not work with Azure DevOps and Bitbucket repositories

@PetroKolosov, I didn't test with the bitbucket repo, but you can refer this document for more details.
